# listen for changes firebase react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the number of likes. 
How can I listen & display the value change ?

In the firebase doc, they say to use .on('value', function (snap)). But how to implement it ? Should I create a new function ? What about state ? Thank you so much !

```
class WordItem extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.onPressIcon = this.onPressIcon.bind(this);
this.state = {
  dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    }),
  }
}



onPressIcon(word){

                var config = {
                apiKey: "",
                authDomain: "",
                databaseURL: ""
                };

                    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

                    let childItem = word+"/likes";
                    console.log(childItem, "childItem")

                    var likes_words = ref.child("items").child(word).child("likes");


                    likes_words.transaction(function(currentLike) {
                        return currentLike + 1;
                        });

            // Sync Object Changes
            likes_words.on('value', function (snap){
              ???
            });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
likes_words.on('value', snapshot => {
      value_of_likes = snapshot.val() 
});
```

Here in value_of_likes you will get you total likes, you can the dispatch action if you are using redux or you can call any other function to update your state

Comment: Alright, it gives me the total likes, but how can I make use of that in render() ?                        this.setState({
                            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(value_of_likes)
                        });

                       console.log(value_of_likes)

Comment: `this.state = {
 value_of_likes: 0
};`

`componentWillMount() {
 this.createDataSource(this.state.value_of_likes);
}`

`createDataSource(value_of_likes) {
 const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
 rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
 });

 this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(value_of_likes);
}`

`render() {
 return (
  <ListView
   enableEmptySections
   dataSource={this.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
  />
 );
}`


`likes_words.on('value', snapshot => {
      value_of_likes = snapshot.val() 
   this.setState({ value_of_likes });
});`

Comment: You can initialise value_of_likes.

Then pass value of likes in this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(value_of_likes);

In render method create ListView with this dataSource.

and when new value_of_likes come, update the state.

Comment: Almost there!
I don't know where to put the likes_words.on. If inside onPressIcon function, i can see in the logs that it increments also the number of times it renders like so: 200, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202

Comment: Thank you ! here it is : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sbdm05/Dictionary/master/components/WordItem.js

Comment: In constructor
      `this.state= {
         value_of_likes: 0
      }`
      And insted of this 
      `this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(value_of_likes)
      });`
      
       write this

      `this.setState({ value_of_likes: value_of_likes})`

Comment: Hey @sohamdodia, just one last thing please! the value of likes starts from zero when you enter the app for the first time, then if you add a like, it shows the number. I added this line <Text>{this.state.value_of_likes}</Text>. 
How can I prevent state to show 0 ?

Comment: `{this.state.value_of_likes !==0
?
<Text>
     this.state.value_of_likes
</Text>
: <Text></Text>}`

Comment: Thank you very much sohamdodia, you've been a great great help!;-)

Comment: Anytime. Whenever you need help, let me know. And upvote the answer.